# How do I Make the program run from the beginning when I input 1

Tags: python

When I run the part where it ask you if you want to stay or leave it it returns to the last `if` or `elif`

```py
    print('If you want to find the circumference type circ\n'
          'If you want the circle area type circa\n'
          'If you want to the triangle area type trga\n')
    option=input()
    stay=0
    while stay != 1:
        if option == 'trga':
            a=float(input('Enter the base size:'))
            b=float(input('Enter the Height:'))
            area=a*b/2
            print('The area is:',area)
            stay=int(input('If you need to continue to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
        elif option == 'circa':
            r=float(input('Enter the radius:'))
            area=r*r*3.14
            print('The area of the circle is:',area)
            stay=int(input('If you need to continute to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
        elif option == 'circ':
            print('Do you have the diameter or the radius ? type r for radius and d for diameter')
            rd=input()
            if rd == 'r':
                r=float(input('Enter the radius:'))
                area=2*3.14*r
                print('The circumfrence is:',area)
                stay=int(input('If you need to continute to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
            elif rd == 'd':
                d=float(input('What is your diameter:'))
                area=d*3.14
                print('The circumference is',area)
                stay=int(input('If you need to continue to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
```

The program is supposed to be able to solve The area of a triangle the circumference of a circle or the area of a circle

Answer (score 0):

```
stay=1
while stay == 1:
    print('If you want to find the circumfrence type circ\n'
          'If you want the circle area type circa\n'
          'If you want to the triangle area type trga\n')
    option=input()
    if option == 'trga':
        a=float(input('Enter the base size:'))
        b=float(input('Enter the Height:'))
        area=a*b/2
        print('The area is:',area)
        stay=int(input('If you need to continute to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
    elif option == 'circa':
        r=float(input('Enter the radius:'))
        area=r*r*3.14
        print('The area of the circle is:',area)
        stay=int(input('If you need to continute to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
    elif option == 'circ':
        print('Do you have the diameter or the radius ? type r for radius and d for diameter')
        rd=input()
        if rd == 'r':
            r=float(input('Enter the radius:'))
            area=2*3.14*r
            print('The circumfrence is:',area)
            stay=int(input('If you need to continute to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
        elif rd == 'd':
            d=float(input('What is your diameter:'))
            area=d*3.14
            print('The circumfrence is',area)
            stay=int(input('If you need to continute to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As @harnath atmakuri has already shown in his code the order of `while stay != 1` and `option = input()` is wrong. You can easily see this by working through you program line by line or with help of a debugger. The Python IDLE has one built in.

The first step is the question what the user wants to calculate:

```py
print('If you want to find the circumference type circ\n'
      'If you want the circle area type circa\n'
      'If you want to the triangle area type trga\n')
option = input()
```

Then the correct calculation is carried out and at the end of every operation

```py
stay=int(input('If you need to continute to use the calculator enter 1 and if you are done enter 0:'))
```

The while loops ends and if `stay != 1` it starts again at the top of the loop. But at this point the user is not asked what he wants another time. Instead `option` stays the same as before and therefore the same calculation is carried out.

To correct the mistake use:

```py
stay=0
while stay != 1:
    print('If you want to find the circumference type circ\n'
          'If you want the circle area type circa\n'
          'If you want to the triangle area type trga\n')
    option=input()
    # and the rest as you had it before inside you while-loop
```

Comment: Some side notes: A variable that is called stay should in my opinion be a bool that is `True` if the user wants to stay and `False` otherwise. The value of pi can be used with `math.pi` after you used `import math` at the top of the script, this will be more accurate that 3.14. There is a [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Maybe its a good time to refactor some functionality in functions.